# Does Juniper support linux RDP terminal session?

Tags: juniper

I have user defined rdp bookmarks on sslvpn but I can't launch that. I get terminal session is not supported. Is there anyway to launch RDP session through vpn? By default it seems it launches Juniper Win32 RDP applet when I click on the bookmark, there is an alternative for ubuntu that would work?

Answer (score 0):

Rdp normally didn't work for Linux, you can use VNC which is inbuilt in Ubuntu. Or you can use TeamViewer which are mostly compatible with Linux, windows and mac